# How does "Injected Class Names" and :: work?

Tags: c++, templates

I read about the Injected Class Name and they showed such an example:

```
template <template<typename> class TT> class X
{

};

template<typename T> class C {
    C* a;
    C<void>& b;
    X<C> c;
    X<::C> d;
};
```

And I'm not sure I understand how it works correctly .For example the line :

```
X<C> c;
```

am I right that this is equivalent to `X<C<T>> c;` ?

But most of all I don't understand what it means `X<::C> d;`
If it sees the class template definition then what will it substitute instead of T? I will be glad to receive answers

Comment: Inside of `template<typename T> class C`, `C` might mean `C<T>`, as in `C* a;`.

Comment: `X` expects a template template parameter, not a type, so `X<C<T>>` is wrong.

Comment: @Jarod42 are the lines ```X<C> c;``` and ```X<::C> d;```  equivalent ? or what is the difference?

Comment: There are equivalent in that context.

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317610/27678)?

Comment: @AndyG yes, thank you, it seems clearer